# react-native-sound throws exception in release apk

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

In IOS it works without issue, in android, its again fine in debug mode,
but in release mode its not working

this is the error message, but not makes sense.. {extra: -2147483648, what: 1}.

```
here is the code:
const Sound = require('react-native-sound')
Sound.setCategory('Ambient')
const music = new Sound('game.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, error => {
  if (error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error))/prompts: {extra: -2147483648, what: 1}
    console.log('failed to create  sound', error)
    return
  }
  alert('load successfully')

})
music.setNumberOfLoops(-1)
```

package.json:

```
..
 "react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-native-sound": "^0.11.0",
```

EDIT: if I refactor code like this; it works.

```
let localSound = require('./game.mp3')
Sound.setCategory('Ambient')
const music = new Sound(localSound, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, error => {
```

why its not getting sound file from '../res/raw/game.mp3' (file is there..)

how to fix this weird issue?